# CSS adjustment div, space beetween top and div.

Tags: css, html, space

When I create a div it always add space to top and left side. Here is an image: http://img265.imageshack.us/img265/7346/83425851cc8d4fc49eb78a9.png

I don't want that space, so what can I do to solve it?

HTML CODE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>Wozzies Blog</title><meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">




    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
body{
  background-image:url('../img/bg.png');
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

#container{
  background-image:url('../img/bgcontentor.png');
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  width: 798px;
  height: 685px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to give 0 to this properties:

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

With this code, space should disappear since, padding and margins are 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to remove the padding (and margins) of your body element:

```
body {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
}
```

I assume that you have already tried to remove the margins on the actual div.
What I usually do is to add this on top of my css file:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

This way, I can set all paddings and margins specific to the elements itself and any default behavior will be ignored (such as the spacing you came across).

Answer (score 0):

What they said - set padding and margins to 0.  And Be The Box - learn the [CSS box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) so you'll know how to manipulate margins, padding, and border to get what you want.